# Applying a function over a groupby object to append a row to each group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a fairly large dataset but for reproducibility, let's say I have the following multi-indexed data frame:

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar','bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
             ['one', 'one','two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,)), index = index)
a[1] = pd.date_range('2017-07-02', periods=10, freq='5min')

a
Out[68]: 
                     0                   1
first second                              
bar   one     0.705488 2017-07-02 00:00:00
      one     0.715645 2017-07-02 00:05:00
      two     0.194648 2017-07-02 00:10:00
baz   one     0.129729 2017-07-02 00:15:00
      two     0.449889 2017-07-02 00:20:00
foo   one     0.031531 2017-07-02 00:25:00
      two     0.320757 2017-07-02 00:30:00
      two     0.876243 2017-07-02 00:35:00
qux   one     0.443682 2017-07-02 00:40:00
      two     0.802774 2017-07-02 00:45:00
```

I want to append the current timestamp as a new row for each group identified by first-second index combinations. (eg. `bar-one`, `bar-two`, etc)

**What I did:**

A function to append the timestamp to each group:

```
def myfunction(g, now):
    g.loc[g.shape[0], 1] = now # current timestamp
    return g
```

Applying the function to a groupby object,

```
# current timestamp
now = pd.datetime.now()

a = a.reset_index().groupby(['first', 'second']).apply(lambda x: myfunction(x, now))
```

This returns:

```
               first second         0                       1
first second                                                 
bar   one    0   bar    one  0.705488 2017-07-02 00:00:00.000
             1   bar    one  0.715645 2017-07-02 00:05:00.000
             2   NaN    NaN       NaN 2017-07-02 02:05:06.442
      two    2   bar    two  0.194648 2017-07-02 00:10:00.000
             1   NaN    NaN       NaN 2017-07-02 02:05:06.442
baz   one    3   baz    one  0.129729 2017-07-02 00:15:00.000
             1   NaN    NaN       NaN 2017-07-02 02:05:06.442
      two    4   baz    two  0.449889 2017-07-02 00:20:00.000
             1   NaN    NaN       NaN 2017-07-02 02:05:06.442
foo   one    5   foo    one  0.031531 2017-07-02 00:25:00.000
             1   NaN    NaN       NaN 2017-07-02 02:05:06.442
      two    6   foo    two  0.320757 2017-07-02 00:30:00.000
             7   foo    two  0.876243 2017-07-02 00:35:00.000
             2   NaN    NaN       NaN 2017-07-02 02:05:06.442
qux   one    8   qux    one  0.443682 2017-07-02 00:40:00.000
             1   NaN    NaN       NaN 2017-07-02 02:05:06.442
      two    9   qux    two  0.802774 2017-07-02 00:45:00.000
             1   NaN    NaN       NaN 2017-07-02 02:05:06.442
```

I can't understand why a new index level has been introduced, however, I can get rid of it and get what I want ultimately:

```
a = a.reset_index(level = 2).drop(('level_2', 'first', 'second')).loc[:,(0,1)]

                     0                       1
first second                                  
bar   one     0.705488 2017-07-02 00:00:00.000
      one     0.715645 2017-07-02 00:05:00.000
      one          NaN 2017-07-02 02:05:06.442
      two     0.194648 2017-07-02 00:10:00.000
      two          NaN 2017-07-02 02:05:06.442
baz   one     0.129729 2017-07-02 00:15:00.000
      one          NaN 2017-07-02 02:05:06.442
      two     0.449889 2017-07-02 00:20:00.000
      two          NaN 2017-07-02 02:05:06.442
foo   one     0.031531 2017-07-02 00:25:00.000
      one          NaN 2017-07-02 02:05:06.442
      two     0.320757 2017-07-02 00:30:00.000
      two     0.876243 2017-07-02 00:35:00.000
      two          NaN 2017-07-02 02:05:06.442
qux   one     0.443682 2017-07-02 00:40:00.000
      one          NaN 2017-07-02 02:05:06.442
      two     0.802774 2017-07-02 00:45:00.000
      two          NaN 2017-07-02 02:05:06.442
```

**Question:**

I'm wondering if there's an elegant, more pandonic way of doing this (Appending a new row to each group and -although not mentioned here - conditionally populating the rest of the fields of that new row other than the timestamp field.)

Comment: _"pandonic"_ - Well _that_ I've never heard before ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can groupby index first, building the additional row you need for each group, then concat it back and sort the df.

```
(
    pd.concat([a, 
               a.groupby(level=[0,1]).first().apply(lambda x: [np.nan,dt.datetime.now()]
               ,axis=1)])
    .sort_index()
)

Out[538]: 
                     0                          1
first second                                     
bar   one     0.587648 2017-07-02 00:00:00.000000
      one     0.974524 2017-07-02 00:05:00.000000
      one          NaN 2017-07-02 15:18:57.503371
      two     0.555171 2017-07-02 00:10:00.000000
      two          NaN 2017-07-02 15:18:57.503371
baz   one     0.832874 2017-07-02 00:15:00.000000
      one          NaN 2017-07-02 15:18:57.503371
      two     0.956891 2017-07-02 00:20:00.000000
      two          NaN 2017-07-02 15:18:57.503371
foo   one     0.872959 2017-07-02 00:25:00.000000
      one          NaN 2017-07-02 15:18:57.503371
      two     0.056546 2017-07-02 00:30:00.000000
      two     0.359184 2017-07-02 00:35:00.000000
      two          NaN 2017-07-02 15:18:57.503371
qux   one     0.301327 2017-07-02 00:40:00.000000
      one          NaN 2017-07-02 15:18:57.503371
      two     0.891815 2017-07-02 00:45:00.000000
      two          NaN 2017-07-02 15:18:57.503371
```

Comment: Thanks! This is simpler.

Comment: Can you say something about [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887892/strange-behavior-when-trying-to-append-a-row-to-each-group-in-a-group-by-object) It's about the function I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
b= a.groupby(level=[0,1]).max()  # the new lines
b[:]= np.NaN, pd.datetime.now()  # updated
a = a.append(b).sort_index()     # appended and sorted
```

Grouping by level keep the structure, so it's easier to manage.

Comment: Thanks!This is simple and I didn't know about the `sort_index()`

Comment: Can you say something about [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887892/strange-behavior-when-trying-to-append-a-row-to-each-group-in-a-group-by-object) It's about the function I wrote.