# Strange behavior when trying to append a row to each group in a group by object

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

This question is about a function behaving in an unexpected manner when applied on two different dataframes - more precisely, groupby objects. Either I'm missing something that is obviously wrong or there's a bug in pandas.

---

I wrote the below function to append a row to each group in a groupby object.[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44865453/appying-a-function-over-a-groupby-object-to-append-a-row-to-each-group) is another question that is related to the function.

```
def myfunction(g, now):

    '''This function appends a row to each group and populates the DTM column value of that row with the current timestamp. Other columns of the new row will have NaN s.
       g: a groupby object
       now: current timestamp

       returns a dataframe that has the current timestamp appended in the DTM column for each group

    '''
        g.loc[g.shape[0], 'DTM'] = now # Appending the current timestamp to a DTM column in each group

        return g
```

---

***We'll run two tests to test the function.***

---

**TEST 1**

It works as expected on the dataframe `a` in the linked question(demonstrated in the above question). Here's a slightly augmented a re-run for more clarity (mostly copy-pasted from the linked question).

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar','bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
             ['one', 'one','two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,)), index = index)


    a
Out[50]: 
                     0
first second          
bar   one     0.134379
      one     0.967928
      two     0.067502
baz   one     0.182887
      two     0.926932
foo   one     0.806225
      two     0.718322
      two     0.932114
qux   one     0.772494
      two     0.141510
```

Applying the function,

```
 a = a.reset_index().groupby(['first', 'second']).apply(lambda x: myfunction(x, now))
```

It has appended a new row to each group. A new `DTM` column was added because it wasn't in the original `a`. A group is a `first` - `second` pair.

```
a
Out[52]: 
               first second         0                     DTM
first second                                                 
bar   one    0   bar    one  0.134379                     NaT
             1   bar    one  0.967928                     NaT
             2   NaN    NaN       NaN 2017-07-03 18:56:33.183
      two    2   bar    two  0.067502                     NaT
             1   NaN    NaN       NaN 2017-07-03 18:56:33.183
baz   one    3   baz    one  0.182887                     NaT
             1   NaN    NaN       NaN 2017-07-03 18:56:33.183
      two    4   baz    two  0.926932                     NaT
             1   NaN    NaN       NaN 2017-07-03 18:56:33.183
foo   one    5   foo    one  0.806225                     NaT
             1   NaN    NaN       NaN 2017-07-03 18:56:33.183
      two    6   foo    two  0.718322                     NaT
             7   foo    two  0.932114                     NaT
             2   NaN    NaN       NaN 2017-07-03 18:56:33.183
qux   one    8   qux    one  0.772494                     NaT
             1   NaN    NaN       NaN 2017-07-03 18:56:33.183
      two    9   qux    two  0.141510                     NaT
             1   NaN    NaN       NaN 2017-07-03 18:56:33.183
```

Some refinement,

```
a = a.reset_index(level = 2).drop(('level_2', 'first', 'second')).loc[:,(0,'DTM')]
```

this gives final `a` as,

```
a
Out[62]: 
                     0                     DTM
first second                                  
bar   one     0.371683                     NaT
      one     0.327870                     NaT
      one          NaN 2017-07-03 18:56:33.183
      two     0.048794                     NaT
      two          NaN 2017-07-03 18:56:33.183
baz   one     0.462747                     NaT
      one          NaN 2017-07-03 18:56:33.183
      two     0.758674                     NaT
      two          NaN 2017-07-03 18:56:33.183
foo   one     0.238607                     NaT
      one          NaN 2017-07-03 18:56:33.183
      two     0.156104                     NaT
      two     0.594270                     NaT
      two          NaN 2017-07-03 18:56:33.183
qux   one     0.091088                     NaT
      one          NaN 2017-07-03 18:56:33.183
      two     0.795864                     NaT
      two          NaN 2017-07-03 18:56:33.183
```

So far so good. This is the expected behavior. A new row has been appended to each `first`-`second` pair and the `DTM` column of that row has been populated with the current timestamp.

---

**TEST 2**

Surprisingly, I couldn't reproduce that behavior in the below dataframe `df`. A group is an `ID`-`SEQ` combination

---

This `df` can be reproduced using:

1.Copying the below

```
    C1  572  5/9/2017 10:13  PE
    C1  572  5/9/2017 12:24  OK
    C1  579  5/9/2017 10:19  PE
    C1  579  5/9/2017 13:25  OK
    C1  587  5/9/2017 10:20  PE
    C1  587  5/9/2017 12:25  OK
    C1  590  5/9/2017 10:21  PE
    C1  590  5/9/2017 13:09  OK
    C1  604  5/9/2017 10:38  PE
    C1  604  5/9/2017 12:32  OK
    C1  609  5/9/2017 10:39  PE
    C1  609  5/9/2017 13:29  OK
    C1  613  5/9/2017 10:39  PE
    C1  613  5/9/2017 13:08  OK
    C1  618  5/9/2017 10:40  PE
    C1  618  5/9/2017 13:33  OK
    C1  636  5/9/2017 10:54  PE
    C1  636  5/9/2017 13:36  OK
    C1  642  5/9/2017 10:55  PE
    C1  642  5/9/2017 13:35  OK
    C1  643  5/9/2017 10:56  PE
    C1  643  5/9/2017 13:34  OK
    C1  656  5/9/2017 10:55  PE
    C1  656  5/9/2017 13:36  OK
    C2  86  9/5/2016 19:45   PE
    C2  86  9/6/2016 11:55   OK
    C3  10  4/17/2017 12:23  PE
    C3  10  4/17/2017 14:51  OK
    C4  38  3/25/2017 10:35  PE
    C4  38  3/25/2017 10:51  OK
```

2.And then executing these,

```
  df = pd.read_clipboard(sep = '[ ]{2,}')
  df.columns = ['ID', 'SEQ', 'DTM', 'STATUS']
```

---

Setting a multi-index

```
d = df.set_index(['ID', 'SEQ', 'DTM']) # I have three index levels this time in the original dataframe
```

What `d` looks like,

```
d
Out[40]: 
                       STATUS
ID SEQ DTM                   
C1 572 5/9/2017 10:13      PE
       5/9/2017 12:24      OK
   579 5/9/2017 10:19      PE
       5/9/2017 13:25      OK
   587 5/9/2017 10:20      PE
       5/9/2017 12:25      OK
   590 5/9/2017 10:21      PE
       5/9/2017 13:09      OK
   604 5/9/2017 10:38      PE
       5/9/2017 12:32      OK
   609 5/9/2017 10:39      PE
       5/9/2017 13:29      OK
   613 5/9/2017 10:39      PE
       5/9/2017 13:08      OK
   618 5/9/2017 10:40      PE
       5/9/2017 13:33      OK
   636 5/9/2017 10:54      PE
       5/9/2017 13:36      OK
   642 5/9/2017 10:55      PE
       5/9/2017 13:35      OK
   643 5/9/2017 10:56      PE
       5/9/2017 13:34      OK
   656 5/9/2017 10:55      PE
       5/9/2017 13:36      OK
C2 86  9/5/2016 19:45      PE
       9/6/2016 11:55      OK
C3 10  4/17/2017 12:23     PE
       4/17/2017 14:51     OK
C4 38  3/25/2017 10:35     PE
       3/25/2017 10:51     OK
```

Applying the function,

```
dd = d.reset_index().groupby(['ID', 'SEQ']).apply(lambda x: myfunction(x, now)) # a group is a unique combination of ID-SEQ pairs
```

This returns, (notice the fourth row)

```
dd
Out[37]: 
            ID    SEQ                         DTM STATUS
ID SEQ                                                  
C1 572 0    C1  572.0              5/9/2017 10:13     PE
       1    C1  572.0              5/9/2017 12:24     OK
       2   NaN    NaN  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
   579 2    C1  579.0  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000     PE
       3    C1  579.0              5/9/2017 13:25     OK
   587 4    C1  587.0              5/9/2017 10:20     PE
       5    C1  587.0              5/9/2017 12:25     OK
       2   NaN    NaN  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
   590 6    C1  590.0              5/9/2017 10:21     PE
       7    C1  590.0              5/9/2017 13:09     OK
       2   NaN    NaN  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
   604 8    C1  604.0              5/9/2017 10:38     PE
       9    C1  604.0              5/9/2017 12:32     OK
       2   NaN    NaN  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
   609 10   C1  609.0              5/9/2017 10:39     PE
       11   C1  609.0              5/9/2017 13:29     OK
       2   NaN    NaN  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
   613 12   C1  613.0              5/9/2017 10:39     PE
       13   C1  613.0              5/9/2017 13:08     OK
       2   NaN    NaN  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
   618 14   C1  618.0              5/9/2017 10:40     PE
       15   C1  618.0              5/9/2017 13:33     OK
       2   NaN    NaN  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
   636 16   C1  636.0              5/9/2017 10:54     PE
       17   C1  636.0              5/9/2017 13:36     OK
       2   NaN    NaN  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
   642 18   C1  642.0              5/9/2017 10:55     PE
       19   C1  642.0              5/9/2017 13:35     OK
       2   NaN    NaN  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
   643 20   C1  643.0              5/9/2017 10:56     PE
       21   C1  643.0              5/9/2017 13:34     OK
       2   NaN    NaN  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
   656 22   C1  656.0              5/9/2017 10:55     PE
       23   C1  656.0              5/9/2017 13:36     OK
       2   NaN    NaN  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
C2 86  24   C2   86.0              9/5/2016 19:45     PE
       25   C2   86.0              9/6/2016 11:55     OK
       2   NaN    NaN  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
C3 10  26   C3   10.0             4/17/2017 12:23     PE
       27   C3   10.0             4/17/2017 14:51     OK
       2   NaN    NaN  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
C4 38  28   C4   38.0             3/25/2017 10:35     PE
       29   C4   38.0             3/25/2017 10:51     OK
       2   NaN    NaN  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
```

some refinement,

```
ddd = dd.reset_index(level = 2).drop(('level_2', 'ID', 'SEQ')).loc[:,('DTM','STATUS')]

ddd
Out[39]: 
                               DTM STATUS
ID SEQ                                   
C1 572              5/9/2017 10:13     PE
   572              5/9/2017 12:24     OK
   572  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
   579  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000     PE
   579              5/9/2017 13:25     OK
   587              5/9/2017 10:20     PE
   587              5/9/2017 12:25     OK
   587  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
   590              5/9/2017 10:21     PE
   590              5/9/2017 13:09     OK
   590  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
   604              5/9/2017 10:38     PE
   604              5/9/2017 12:32     OK
   604  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
   609              5/9/2017 10:39     PE
   609              5/9/2017 13:29     OK
   609  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
   613              5/9/2017 10:39     PE
   613              5/9/2017 13:08     OK
   613  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
   618              5/9/2017 10:40     PE
   618              5/9/2017 13:33     OK
   618  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
   636              5/9/2017 10:54     PE
   636              5/9/2017 13:36     OK
   636  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
   642              5/9/2017 10:55     PE
   642              5/9/2017 13:35     OK
   642  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
   643              5/9/2017 10:56     PE
   643              5/9/2017 13:34     OK
   643  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
   656              5/9/2017 10:55     PE
   656              5/9/2017 13:36     OK
   656  2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
C2 86               9/5/2016 19:45     PE
   86               9/6/2016 11:55     OK
   86   2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
C3 10              4/17/2017 12:23     PE
   10              4/17/2017 14:51     OK
   10   2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
C4 38              3/25/2017 10:35     PE
   38              3/25/2017 10:51     OK
   38   2017-07-03 18:56:33.183000    NaN
```

**Problem**

A new row containing the current timestamp has been appended to each `ID`-`SEQ` group with the exception of `C1`-`579` group! (4th row in `dd` and `ddd`)

---

**Questions**

1. What caused this problem?
2. What is the additional index level introduced in `dd`?

Comment: You're more likely to get responses if you can make the question inclusive of all the information required, rather than linking to other sources and saying "I'm trying to do this". Also, simplify your code and example to the simplest case in which the issue still occurs to make it easier for people to understand

Comment: @mjp Thanks for the suggestion. I have restructured the question. This is a question I desperately want an answer to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot debugging problem was noticed.

There is problem with same number in level `3` - in your last sample is shape of group `2`, but this value exist before, so new row was no added onlu row was overwritten.

```
            ID    SEQ                        DTM STATUS
ID SEQ                                                 
C1 572 0    C1  572.0 2017-05-09 10:13:00.000000     PE
       1    C1  572.0 2017-05-09 12:24:00.000000     OK
       2   NaN    NaN 2017-07-06 08:46:02.341472    NaN
   579 2    C1  579.0 2017-07-06 08:46:02.341472     PE <- ovetwritten values in row
       3    C1  579.0 2017-05-09 13:25:00.000000     OK
   587 4    C1  587.0 2017-05-09 10:20:00.000000     PE
       5    C1  587.0 2017-05-09 12:25:00.000000     OK
       2   NaN    NaN 2017-07-06 08:46:02.341472    NaN
```

First sample was nice because second group has only one row.

But if has 2 rows:

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar','bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
             ['one', 'two','two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,)), index = index)
print (a)
                     0
first second          
bar   one     0.366258
      two     0.583205
      two     0.159388
baz   one     0.598198
      two     0.274027
foo   one     0.086461
      two     0.353577
      two     0.823377
qux   one     0.098737
      two     0.128470
```

same problem.

```
print (a)
               first second         0                        DTM
first second                                                    
bar   one    0   bar    one  0.366258                        NaT
             1   NaN    NaN       NaN 2017-07-06 08:47:55.610671
      two    1   bar    two  0.583205                        NaT
             2   bar    two  0.159388 2017-07-06 08:47:55.610671 <- ovetwritten 
baz   one    3   baz    one  0.598198                        NaT
             1   NaN    NaN       NaN 2017-07-06 08:47:55.610671
      two    4   baz    two  0.274027                        NaT
```

So if function is a bit changed all works perfectly:

```
now = pd.datetime.now()

def myfunction(g, now):

    g.loc[str(g.shape[0]) + 'a', 'DTM'] = now 
    return g

arrays = [['bar', 'bar','bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
             ['one', 'two','two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,)), index = index)
print (a)


a = a.reset_index().groupby(['first', 'second']).apply(lambda x: myfunction(x, now))
print (a)
                first second         0                        DTM
first second                                                     
bar   one    0    bar    one  0.677641                        NaT
             1a   NaN    NaN       NaN 2017-07-06 08:54:47.481671
      two    1    bar    two  0.274588                        NaT
             2    bar    two  0.524903                        NaT
             2a   NaN    NaN       NaN 2017-07-06 08:54:47.481671
baz   one    3    baz    one  0.198272                        NaT
             1a   NaN    NaN       NaN 2017-07-06 08:54:47.481671
      two    4    baz    two  0.787949                        NaT
             1a   NaN    NaN       NaN 2017-07-06 08:54:47.481671
foo   one    5    foo    one  0.484197                        NaT
             1a   NaN    NaN       NaN 2017-07-06 08:54:47.481671
```

Comment: First, thanks A LOT for  answering! I'm not sure if I got this correctly. Could you please make an edit to the below for more clarity? `There is problem with same number in level 3 - in your last sample is shape of group 2, but this value exist before, so new row was no added onlu row was overwritten.`

Comment: @akilat90 - thanks for suggestion. If think some grammar can be better, no problem if improve my answer ;) You can edit it without problem ;)

Comment: Thanks - English isn't my first tongue either :) but I will edit it once I've completely understood how has this happened. Regarding that new addition of a level ( question #2 in my question); can you explain why a new level has been introduced? And what dictates its value? Maybe I need to read more on `df.loc`

Comment: @akilat90 - no, it is more simplier. Numbers are from original index - `a = a.reset_index()` create `index=0,1,2..`.  And if  need remove index created from groups is possible use `a = a.reset_index().groupby(['first', 'second'],group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: myfunction(x, now))`.

Comment: So then `a.reset_index().groupby(['first', 'second']).head()` should show three index levels ? (it isn't)

Btw, what I understood by `this value exist before` in your answer is that the index `C1-579-2` is repeating. Also `bar-two-2` in `a` you created is repeating. Is it right?

Comment: No, there are 2 different things. First reset index create from all levels columns and create defulat index. And `apply` vs `head` - each is implemented different, so output is too different. `apply` is more generaly so more problematic. And for second question - exacly, you are right.

Comment: So that's it. I would never be able to come up with `g.loc[str(g.shape[0]) + 'a', 'DTM'] = now` and thanks a lot for your time, availability and patience! There should be a way to reward more for efforts of this kind!

Comment: Glad can help, it was very interesting problem. Good luck!